# Why does XNA create two GraphicsDeviceManager services?

Tags: xna, graphics-programming

While working with XNA today, I looked at the debugger information for `Game.Services` to retrieve the `GraphicsDeviceManager` so that a component could utilize it. Instead, I found two different objects:

- [IGraphicsDeviceManager, GraphicsDeviceManager] `KeyValuePair<Type, object>`
- [IGraphicsDeviceService, GraphicsDeviceManager] `KeyValuePair<Type, object>`

Or rather, what I *assume* to be one instance of an object, but indexed according to two different interfaces. Why?

*(For context, I'm trying to understand all the different Graphics/Device classes so I can make a ScreenComponent that moves it cleanly away from the main Game object.)*